# Why some dockers use docker network instead of the link parameter?

Tags: docker

I'm learning to use docker, there is something I don't get. The [Etherpad Lite image for docker](https://store.docker.com/community/images/tvelocity/etherpad-lite) links the mysql db like this :

> ```
> $ docker network create ep_network
> $ docker run -d --network ep_network \
>              -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password --name ep_mysql mysql
> ```
>
> Finally you can start an instance of Etherpad Lite:
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d \
>     --network ep_network \
>     -e ETHERPAD_DB_HOST=ep_mysql \
>     -e ETHERPAD_DB_PASSWORD=password \
>     -p 9001:9001 \
>     tvelocity/etherpad-lite
> ```

Is it possible to do the same with the `--link` option? Like the [odoo](https://store.docker.com/images/odoo) container does:

> Start a PostgreSQL server
>
> ```
> $ docker run -d -e POSTGRES_USER=odoo -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=odoo \
>              --name db postgres:9.4
> ```
>
> Start an Odoo instance
>
> ```
> $ docker run -p 8069:8069 --name odoo --link db:db -t odoo
> ```

1. why Etherpad uses `docker network` and why odoo uses `--link` ?
2. in wich case(s) I should use the first way instead of the second one ?
3. some dockers have no information on the hub/store, so how can I figure how I have to link containers ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very simple answer: `docker --link` is a deprecated feature and shouldn't be used. For any new deployments use `docker network` instead.

See https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/dockerlinks/ for more info.

I guess the `odoo` documentation is old and hasn't been updated to use `docker network` style yet.

On the other hand yes, you can still `--link` mysql container with `etherpad` but bear in mind that it's a deprecated way of doing things.